# Counting the bigram frequencies of a specific pair of words in a list using python without NLTK

Tags: python, nlp

For example, I have a list of words['car','hamburger','airplane',.........,'hamburger']. How can I count the frequency of bigram (car,hamburger) without using NLTK?

Comment: The frequency of the bigram where?

Comment: I want to find the frequency of word pair ('car','hamburger') in the list